# Group multiline columns in a block under column 1 as a header in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed, tr

Working with log files columns and want do the following:

input:

```
04.04.2018 11:52:44.014 123abc
04.04.2018 11:52:44.014 abc123
04.04.2018 11:52:44.014 xyz

04.04.2018 11:52:46.023 456abc
04.04.2018 11:52:46.023 dddfff
04.04.2018 11:52:46.023 zzz111
04.04.2018 11:52:46.023 d
```

desired output:

```
04.04.2018 11:52:44.014 123abcabc123xyz
04.04.2018 11:52:46.023 456abcdddfffzzz111d
```

I have tried awk so far:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n";message="";time=$1}{message+=$3} END {print time; print message}'
```

With above awk I want to recognize a block by an empty line separator, then get the date and time from line1 column1&2, then concatenate a message for every line in a block in column 3. In the end print time and final message. But it doesn't do what I thought it would..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grouping blocks without checking the date/time fields

```
$ awk '!NF {print line; line=""; next} 
           {line=(line?line $NF:$0)} 
       END {print line}' file 

04.04.2018 11:52:44.014 123abcabc123xyz
04.04.2018 11:52:46.023 456abcdddfffzzz111d
```

Comment: This works even when the time inside the log block changes! Good solution, thanks, although I don't completely understand it :).

Answer (score 2):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk 'NF{a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2] $NF:$NF} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' SUBSEP=" "   Input_file
```

***EDIT:*** In case we need to have the output in same sequence as per Input_file then following may help you.

```
awk '!b[$1,$2]++ && NF{c[++i]=$1 FS $2} NF{a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2] $NF:$NF} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){print c[j],a[c[j]]}}' SUBSEP=" "  Input_file
```

Comment: This will not going to work if the log time for a block has even a slightest change, eg: at the start of the block the time is: 04.04.2018 11:52:46.023, then it could change to 04.04.2018 11:52:46.025.

Comment: @Code_So1dier, you haven't mentioned that in your post, else I would have written solution as per that.

Answer (score 1):

52 character single stanza mawk solution (when golfed, golfing not shown):

```
awk 'NF { if (!seen[$1$2]++) printf "\n%s %s ", $1, $2; printf $3 }' file
```

On non-empty lines (where NF, the number of fields, is nonzero): if we haven't seen the date/time before, print a newline, the date, time, and a space. Then always print the third column.

This does not require the empty space between entries in order to merge them.  I prefer [mawk for portability](https://superuser.com/questions/75875/awk-mawk-nawk-gawk-what/75885#75885) (the [ternary operator `?:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) used in other answers here is unique to [gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/)).

---

The comments requested a version of this that truncates the milliseconds off. Here is a solution that does that (note that the output is changed too; see my comment for how to retain the first conflicting time's milliseconds):

```
awk 'NF { key="$1 " substr($2,1,8); if (!seen[key]++) printf "\n%s ", key; printf $3 }' file
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but it will not work if there is a slight deviation in the log time, eg if at the start the time is 04.04.2018 11:52:46.023, and it changes slightly (04.04.2018 11:52:46.025) then it is considered as a separate entry

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question.  My solution works if you change the conditional to `if(!seen[$1 substr($2,1,8)]++)` but I don't know how you want the output to look (the milliseconds output would be wrong for later entries).